# Multidimensional Array syntax in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Is the following code valid for assigning keys and data into a multi-dimensional array in PHP 5.3 and if not what's the alternetive? I know it works in 5.4 not sure about 5.3.

```
   $agent_array = $agent_name= []
$agent_array [$agent_name[0]][] = $agent_name[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5.3` doesnot support shorthand array syntax. You need to use `array()`. The code will be -

```
$agent_array = $agent_name= array();
```

The rest should work.